# Unable to delete all the records from table but its deleting only one record using selenium java

Tags: java, oop, selenium-webdriver, automation, build-automation

Trying to delete remove button after adding the products
used for loop to delete the records one by one before signout the testcase

But its deleting only one record ,i would like to delete the records until its reach to table count zero

```
   ` List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(xpath);
        // For loop follows
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            // Access individual elements this way:
            WebElement deleteButton = driver.findElement(xpath);
            deleteButton.click();
        }`
```

Comment: So you have one remove button that delete the rows? Or does each row have the remove button?

Comment: yes i have multiple rows with remove btn and current code is working with delete the only one remove button .my question is to delete the all the rows remote button until the table size equal to zero

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should search from root element from each row.
It looks like you are trying to click on the same element in your loop each time.

Try this

```js
 List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(rowsXpath);
        // For loop follows
 for (WebElement element: rows) {
            // Access individual elements this way:
            WebElement deleteButton = element.findElement(deleteButtonXpath);
            deleteButton.click();
            // there I suggest to add some wait for rows amount to be decreased
}`
```

Comment: Yes i used these code but still its deleting the first row remove button and how can i implement to delete the multiple rows with remove button ?

Comment: Can you share your DOM?

Comment: Hi Im not sure i can share DOM here

Comment: yes its started working now just modified table xpath ..thanks